# In Xamarin, how to check if any DisplayAlert or DisplayActionSheet is currently open?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, alert

Before doing a particular action- say taking a screenshot, in any page in my App I need to check if any DisplayAlert or DisplayActionSheet is already open;If any, I need to close it.

Comment: I do not think that it is possible, you can maybe play with booleans and all but I do not think that would be reliable

Comment: Agree with G.hakim, it cannot be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the opening of a DisplayAlert or DisplayActionSheet, and you can track which option a user has selected on them, but you can't track if a user clicks outside the Alert or ActionSheet to dismiss them.

But you could instead use a [Modally presented page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/modal), so that you it acts as Dismissible alert/action sheet, that will help you track when the modal is opened, and when the modal is dismissed. Since users can't click outside the modal to dismiss it, you won't have that disadvantage here. Thus you will know if that display is already open for your screenshot. Let me know if it makes sense